# Java client cant connect with NodeJS server on heroku

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, heroku

So I have this Javascript server:

```
const net = require('net');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

net.createServer(function (sock){
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ":" + sock.remotePort);

    sock.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    sock.on('close', function(data){
        console.log('DISCONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ":" + sock.remotePort);

    });

    sock.on('error', function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });

}).listen(port, '0.0.0.0');

console.log('Listening on: ' + port);
```

And I use this to connect my Java client:

```
public void connect () {
    System.out.println("Connecting with: " + host + ":" + port);
    try {
        this.socket = new Socket(this.host, this.port);
        System.out.println("Connected!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And it works when I try it local but whenever I upload it to heroku it never logs a CONNECTED message or any received data so I don't think it connects.

I'm using this as ip/port to connect my client: .herokuapp.com:heroku.env.PORT not literally ofcourse, I use the port heroku gives to my application on launch since I do see the Listening on:  message.

Am I doing something wrong? Or does heroku not support sockets?

Answer (score 0):

Your client should connect to `<appname>.herokuapp.com` on port 80 or 443. The `PORT` var is for internal binding only.

Comment: Soo do I need to change my server setup? Cause when I tried connecting to `<appname>.herokuapp.com:80|443` my client says it connects but my server doesn't log anything. I tried changing the listen port to 80 but then I get a EEACCES error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your server binds to `$PORT`. Your client connects to 80|443